# How to ensure that my Java program runs in best performance on Intellij

Tags: java, environment-variables, virtual-machine

Do I need to make a java release in order to get the best performance or just using the run command from Intellij will do?

Is there any environment flags or vm options that I need to turn on or the default will give the best performance?

In my case I really do not need any debugging information.